# Proving that $c_c(\mathbb N)$ is a dense subset of $l^p(\mathbb N)$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

Proving that $c_c(\mathbb N)$ is a dense subset of $l^p(\mathbb N)$

$c_c(\mathbb N)$-space of sequences which are zero after finitely many terms.
$$l_p=\{(x_i)^{\infty}_{i=1}|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i|^p<\infty\}$$

Comment: Well I haven't done these types of questions, so I basically don't know where to begin; I need this for another proof.

Comment: Sketch of the proof: for all $\{ x_i \}_i \in l^p$, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some index $N \ge 1$ such that $$\sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}|x_i|^p <  \varepsilon$$ now, truncate $\{ x_i \}_i$ at index $N$.

Comment: The typical approach is to approximate $x \in \ell^p$ with a (sequence of) suitable elements from $c_c(\mathbb{N})$. You may first answer the question: "What is the best approximation of $x$ with an element $y \in c_c$ with $y_i = 0$ for $i > N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e_n$ the sequence which is only $0$ except in the $n^{th}$ term where it is $1$. Let $f \in l^p$ and let $u_n = \sum_{k=1}^n f(k)e_k$. We will show that $u_n \in c_c$ converges to $f$ in $l^p$, so it shows that $c_c$ is dense in $l^p$.

$$||f-u_n||_p=||f-\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)e_k||_p=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}|f(k)|^p$$

Which tends to $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$. So  $c_c$ is dense in $l^p$.